# macbook air keeps restarting bc of a problem (filevault decrypting is stuck in 99)

Tags: encryption, filevault

I turned my FileVault off (yes big mistake) without researching anything. I don't know what made me turn it off brain fart or curiosity maybe.

t was all okay until the decryption reached 99% when I plug in my laptop to the charger, My laptop restarts on its own, is it supposed to do that?

The battery drains fast when I try to use my laptop (charger unplugged).

I have tried disabling and enabling it from terminal but it ends up only showing this

```
$ sudo fdesetup disable
Password:
Enter the user name://
Enter the password for user '//':
FileVault was not disabled (2).


$ fdesetup status
FileVault is On.
Decryption in progress: Percent completed = 99
```

I don't know how to fix it or what to do, I'm not sure if it's supposed to do that.

Comment: Relevant info missing:  How big is your HD/SSD, and how long did you wait for FileVault to complete?

Answer (score 0):

In brief: this is supposed to work.  Turning off FDE is not a great idea, but you *should* be able to turn it off and on again without issue. It's not your fault that you simply tried to use this basic feature of the operating system.

Definitely your laptop restarting itself without warning is a bad sign.  If you still can, I would recommend making a time machine backup as soon as possible so you don't lose your data, and taking your device to the genius bar.

I can't say more without having examined the machine closely (and even then, I personally probably couldn't, I'm not a hardware expert) but the machine restarting sounds like a bad sign, like it's hit some bad hardware in some part of that 99th percentile of disk which is causing a crash.